# Permission error when writing files in django + ubuntu + apache

Tags: django, apache, ubuntu

Following is the error message I receive when I save x.mp3 via django :

```sh
Exception Type: PermissionError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'x.mp3'
```

Comment: This is the line in views.py which gives error : alpha.save('x.mp3')

Answer (score -1):

You should use the sudo command for super user.
because, the sudo enables the full access to files in your system.
So use sudo command to write the files for x.mp3
You can use this command in all linux platforms like kali,ubuntu,django,parrot.
Problem solved.
If you have any questions please be free to ask.
Vote for me

Comment: This is the line in views.py which gives error : alpha.save('x.mp3')